# How to verify purchase of a Play Store app (vs. verifying in-app purchases)

Tags: android, google-play

The documentation at https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html describes how to verify in-app purchases and subscriptions. But it's unclear how to verify the purchase of the app itself.

Is there a programmatic way to accomplish this? Preferably in a way that ties back to the device ID on which the app was purchased?

Comment: I think App licensing could be what you are looking for: http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html

Comment: I can't see where the app licensing API actually exposes to the programmer a signed statement from Google indicating that the app has been purchased. Even the raw mode does not seem to provide this. Am I missing something?